# Ретроспектива слов "намедни, давеча, недавно"

Tags: семантика

Можно ли употреблять слова *намедни, давеча, недавно,* обсуждая то, что случилось всего лишь час назад?

Comment: Можно ли употребить слово *давным-давно*, обсуждая то, что случилось, кажется, в прошлую пятницу?

Comment: Нет, давным-давно не стоит, говоря о пятнице

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Наме́дни](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8) — наречие, разг. Недавно, **на днях.** *Намедни ходили на рыбалку. Намедни брат заходил.*
У Фасмера: намедни — недавно, наме́днись, наме́сь, ономня́сь, наме́днях – то же. Из др.-русск. местн. п. ед. ч. ономь дьни, стар. ономь дьне...

[Да́веча](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0&all=x) — наречие, нар.-разг. Некоторое время тому назад; недавно. *Вам давеча посылку принесли. Давеча ты обидел меня. Слыхали, какое давеча наводнение было?*

[Недавно](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE&all=x) — наречие. Незадолго до настоящего времени, в недалёком прошлом; с недавнего времени. *Недавно была гроза. Недавно были в театре. Ты поселился здесь недавно?*

"Намедни" и "давеча" — это синонимы наречия "недавно". Не думаю, что эти слова (по определению) можно употреблять, говоря о произошедшем час назад.

Вот предложения, в которых можно "отсчитать время обратно":
*...еще солнце русской поэзии (наше все) писал своему другу об одном (одной) гении чистой красоты, что **намедни** (не помню, не то вчера, не то позавчера)...* (В. Ханан);
*У меня, как ты не успела заметить, день рождения был **давеча*** (А. Кирилин);
*Не то я купнулся **давеча** на свежем, сверх всякой умной меры освежающем, ветерке, не то повернулся неловко уже с утра* (А. Смирнов).